# Getting Access Denied for pulling object from S3 bucket from ECS using IAM Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I am trying to get some encrypted connection parameter from s3 bucket in my sample Spring application. Here is the method I am using to run inside a container:

```
public void encryptionOnly_KmsManagedKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

     AmazonS3Encryption s3Encryption = AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
            .withCryptoConfiguration(new CryptoConfiguration(CryptoMode.AuthenticatedEncryption))
            // Can either be Key ID or alias (prefixed with 'alias/')
            .withEncryptionMaterials(new KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider("alias/db-connstring"))
            .build();

    //System.out.println(amazonS3.getObjectAsString(BUCKET_NAME, PROPERTIES_FILE_NON_ENC));
    System.out.println(s3Encryption.getObjectAsString(BUCKET_NAME, PROPERTIES_FILE_ENC));

}
```

I have created an IAM role and assigned to my ECS task:

```
{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Action": [ "s3:GetObject" ], "Sid": "Stmt1", "Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::dev-web-s3/dev-webapp.properties" ], "Effect": "Allow" } ] }
```

I am getting below error:

```
15:31:25,502 WARN  [com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) SSL Certificate checking for endpoints has been explicitly disabled.
15:31:25,523 WARN  [com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) SSL Certificate checking for endpoints has been explicitly disabled.
15:31:26,000 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 6859B84E52157DB7), S3 Extended Request ID: hIneAhT8TYX3P1z8zOGetqrSHhz5AqeOtRQnkCU9IuR0mBpMntFE9TXySu2iYv0Bbs4xONkxRz0=
15:31:26,001 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1588)
15:31:26,001 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1258)
15:31:26,001 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
15:31:26,001 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
15:31:26,002 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
15:31:26,002 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
15:31:26,002 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
15:31:26,002 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
15:31:26,002 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1)  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
```

I am using Fargate to deploy my containers so could not go inside the containers but ran below command and got result as below:
*curl 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI*

```
{
"RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::281177187806:role/CC_GetPropertiesFile_S3_Role",
"AccessKeyId": "REDACTED",
"SecretAccessKey": "REDACTED",
"Token": "some random token",
"Expiration": "2018-03-16T00:21:55Z"
}
```

CC_GetPropertiesFile_S3_Role is the role which was created earlier for which the trusted entities is AWS service: ecs-tasks.

I tried to use the credentials from the CURL command using BasicAWSCredentials options and got below error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID: 81CC7254BCA83D53), S3 Extended Request ID: of46B2ujyTG
```

I am trying to get debug-level logging information but meanwhile any other issues which can be pointed out or alternative solution provided is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to your S3 access problem, you should consider using Parameter Store for the storage of secrets such as DB credentials.

Comment: @jarmod True, Parameter Store seems to be alternative solution but not able to find much help in writing a java code for getting encrypted credentials from store.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding my Custom Role *CC_GetPropertiesFile_S3_Role* in the encryption key which I was using in the java method.

Answer (score 0):

You must use two different Amazon Resource Names (ARNs) to specify bucket-level (ListBucket) and object-level(GetObject) permissions.

Credentials from IAM will have an expiration time, Hence the `does not exist` error.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::dev-web-s3"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::dev-web-s3/dev-webapp.properties"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @sudharsaan, Thanks for the reply. I tried with the above policy and still got the same error.